# Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError()

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, background-process

I don't know why but this error occurs after reset the app - on first launch everything is working but if close and start the app once again it stucks on splash screen and on the Xcode I got this error:

```
Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier %lu (0x%lx), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug
```

Image attached:

[image]

I am using cordova background geolocation and cordova background mode, but the geolocation is still not set in the first screen part and the background mode is maybe causes the problem?

In Xcode I have enabled like the following image:

[image]

I have just updated the Xcode version to the newest from AppStore on Mac.